# How to run lapply on a list of lists to generate a report table for each list

Tags: r, functional-programming

I have a `list` of `lists` containing summed frequencies that I would like to run a `function` on to generate a table of results for each `list` using `lapply`.

Given these data:

```
# Exemplary list of lists
list1 <- list (1, 2, 3) 
list2 <- list (4, 5, 6)
list3 <- list (7, 8, 9)
names(list1) <- c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
names(list2) <- c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
names(list3) <- c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
lol <- list(list1, list2, list3)

# Function for returning absolute numbers (counts) and percentage
fun_freq <- lapply(lol, function(x) {
  c(n=x, 
    Percent=(x/(Reduce('+',x)) * 100)) 
})

# Transposing output from fun_freq, set rounding options
stratified_dat <- data.frame(t(sapply(fun_freq,c))) %>%
  mutate_at(2, round, 1)

# Setting colnames and rownames
colnames(stratified_dat) <- c ("n", "%")
rownames(stratified_dat) <- c ("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
stratified_dat
```

My current approach seems to work fine if I select a single `list`, e.g. `lol[[1]]`. However, running the `function` across multiple `lists` that are in a `list` of `lists` to get a frequency table for each `list` seems to be a problem. How do I need to modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that while @daniel-o generated a great answer using your methodology and function, I don't think the math is right.  As in I don't think you want 100% for every percent.  I'm not very good with `lapply` and prefer `purrr` and the rest of the `tidyverse`.  So here's an alternate answer that I believe does the calculations you want.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tidyr)

map_dfr(lol, `[`, c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"), .id = "Which_list") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("arg"), values_to = "n") %>%
  group_by(Which_list) %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n) * 100)

#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   Which_list [3]
#>   Which_list name      n   pct
#>   <chr>      <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 1          arg1      1  16.7
#> 2 1          arg2      2  33.3
#> 3 1          arg3      3  50  
#> 4 2          arg1      4  26.7
#> 5 2          arg2      5  33.3
#> 6 2          arg3      6  40  
#> 7 3          arg1      7  29.2
#> 8 3          arg2      8  33.3
#> 9 3          arg3      9  37.5
```

Your data:

```r
# Exemplary list of lists
list1 <- list (1, 2, 3) 
list2 <- list (4, 5, 6)
list3 <- list (7, 8, 9)
names(list1) <- c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
names(list2) <- c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
names(list3) <- c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
lol <- list(list1, list2, list3)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thank for providing a suggestion besides the ```lapply``` approach. I also like working with ```tidyverse```. And yes, you were right regarding the math for the percentage column. However, running ```fun_freq``` on a single list as presented below seems work. 
```fun_freq <- lapply(lol[[1]], function(x) {
  c(n=x, 
    Percent=(x/(Reduce('+',lol[[1]])) * 100)) 
}) ```

Comment: Lot's of viable answers here, enjoy.

Comment: Definitely! Interestingly, one thing that is common in your approach and the one from @user12728748 is that both of you seem to use long data format to tackle this problem. So this is one thing I should remember when facing this type of data again.

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the lists like this

```
for(lmao in lol){


fun_freq <- lapply(lmao, function(x) {
  c(n=x, 
    Percent=(x/(Reduce('+',x)) * 100)) 
})

# Transposing output from fun_freq, set rounding options
stratified_dat <- data.frame(t(sapply(fun_freq,c))) %>%
  mutate_at(2, round, 1)

# Setting colnames and rownames
colnames(stratified_dat) <- c ("n", "%")
rownames(stratified_dat) <- c ("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")
print(stratified_dat)

}
```

output

```
     n   %
arg1 1 100
arg2 2 100
arg3 3 100
     n   %
arg1 4 100
arg2 5 100
arg3 6 100
     n   %
arg1 7 100
arg2 8 100
arg3 9 100
```

**Edit:**

alternatively, depending on your data and expected output, you could try

```
lol <- unlist(lol,recursive=F)
```

with your original code you'd get

```
  n   %
1 1 100
2 2 100
3 3 100
4 4 100
5 5 100
6 6 100
7 7 100
8 8 100
9 9 100
```

Comment: @Daniel O That's nice :) Do you also know if there is some way I can use nested structures of ```apply``` to ```lmao``` on ```lol```?

Comment: you certainly can, its just terrible to understand. For example: `lapply( lol, function(x) sapply(x, max))` It quickly becomes unreadable. And unless every operation is vectorized there will be no benefit to using `lapply` over a `for` loop

Comment: Yep, a code containing multiple instances of ```lapply``` doesn't look like a convenient way to do it. I guess for this analysis I will have to choose one of the solutions provided here. So thank you all for your thoughts and ideas!

Answer (score 1):

I may misunderstand what you are trying to calculate here, but if you want the fraction of arg1, arg2, arg3 for each list, or the fraction of arg, arg2, arg3 across all lists, you could do the following to get the proportions:

```r
lol <- setNames(list(
  setNames(as.list(1:3), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")),
  setNames(as.list(4:6), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")),
  setNames(as.list(7:9), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"))
),  paste0("list", 1:3))
loldf <- do.call(rbind, lapply(lol, unlist))
loldf
#>       arg1 arg2 arg3
#> list1    1    2    3
#> list2    4    5    6
#> list3    7    8    9

# proportion of each argument per list
round(100*prop.table(loldf, 1), 2)
#>        arg1  arg2 arg3
#> list1 16.67 33.33 50.0
#> list2 26.67 33.33 40.0
#> list3 29.17 33.33 37.5

# proportion of single arguments over lists
round(100*prop.table(loldf, 2), 2)
#>        arg1  arg2  arg3
#> list1  8.33 13.33 16.67
#> list2 33.33 33.33 33.33
#> list3 58.33 53.33 50.00
```

If you like `data.table`, you could achieve the same results (split here into lists) like this:

```r
library(data.table)
lol <- setNames(list(
  setNames(as.list(1:3), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")),
  setNames(as.list(4:6), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")),
  setNames(as.list(7:9), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"))
),  paste0("list", 1:3))
lmao <- melt(rbindlist(lol, idcol = "name"), id.vars="name")

# proportion of each argument per list
split(lmao[, .(arg=unique(variable), n=value, Percent=round(100*value/sum(value), 2)), 
    by=.(name)], by="name", keep.by = FALSE)
#> $list1
#>     arg n Percent
#> 1: arg1 1   16.67
#> 2: arg2 2   33.33
#> 3: arg3 3   50.00
#> 
#> $list2
#>     arg n Percent
#> 1: arg1 4   26.67
#> 2: arg2 5   33.33
#> 3: arg3 6   40.00
#> 
#> $list3
#>     arg n Percent
#> 1: arg1 7   29.17
#> 2: arg2 8   33.33
#> 3: arg3 9   37.50

# proportion of single arguments over lists
split(lmao[, .(list=unique(name), n=value, Percent=round(100*value/sum(value), 2)), 
    by=.(variable)], by="variable", keep.by = FALSE)
#> $arg1
#>     list n Percent
#> 1: list1 1    8.33
#> 2: list2 4   33.33
#> 3: list3 7   58.33
#> 
#> $arg2
#>     list n Percent
#> 1: list1 2   13.33
#> 2: list2 5   33.33
#> 3: list3 8   53.33
#> 
#> $arg3
#>     list n Percent
#> 1: list1 3   16.67
#> 2: list2 6   33.33
#> 3: list3 9   50.00
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

**Edit:** `tidyverse` version

Below is a version using `tidyverse` functions instead of `data.table`, if you prefer that.

```r
library(tidyverse)
lol <- setNames(list(
  setNames(as.list (1:3), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")),
  setNames(as.list (4:6), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3")),
  setNames(as.list (7:9), c("arg1", "arg2", "arg3"))
),  paste0("list", 1:3))


lol %>% bind_rows(,.id="list") %>% 
  pivot_longer(-list) %>% 
  group_by(list) %>% 
  mutate(Percent=round(100*value/sum(value), 2)) %>% 
  split(., .$list)
#> $list1
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   list [1]
#>   list  name  value Percent
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 list1 arg1      1    16.7
#> 2 list1 arg2      2    33.3
#> 3 list1 arg3      3    50  
#> 
#> $list2
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   list [1]
#>   list  name  value Percent
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 list2 arg1      4    26.7
#> 2 list2 arg2      5    33.3
#> 3 list2 arg3      6    40  
#> 
#> $list3
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   list [1]
#>   list  name  value Percent
#>   <chr> <chr> <int>   <dbl>
#> 1 list3 arg1      7    29.2
#> 2 list3 arg2      8    33.3
#> 3 list3 arg3      9    37.5
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: My goal is presenting the proportion of each argument per list. Although I have not worked with ```data.table``` before, this is a concise solution. If I understand your code right, you are using a long data format with ```melt``` and subsequently split this longer ```list``` by ```name``` previously defined in ```setNames``` while in the step calculating the additional column for percent.

Comment: Correct. I have added a version using `tidyverse` functions, if you prefer those.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I really appreciate that you took the time to add a ```tidyverse``` suggestion to your answer. If I could upvote one more time I'd definitely do.